# Capturar datos de firebase con angularfire2

Tags: firebase, ionic3

intento realizar una aplicación que tiene un chat interno en donde los usuarios se pueden enviar mensajes entre si y tengo el siguiente modelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la pregunta es, ¿como logro capturar las rooms en donde tengo los id de los chats registrados en los que he o me han enviado un mensaje?

la idea es tener una lista de los chats con el siguiente formato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionar el inconveniente siguiendo las guías de la librería de angular para firebase

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

lo que derivo en una simple instruccion

```
private db: AngularFireDatabase

this.db.list("/chats/rooms/" + room, ref => ref.orderByChild(fromorto).equalTo(userId).limitToFirst(1)).valueChanges();
```